# GoDaddy domain not pointing to Heroku app

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to point my GoDaddy domain to Heroku app. I followed the steps given here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain but I'm unable to access my Heroku app. Here are my DNS records settings:

[image]

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

cname only allow you to point subdomain, so this case you should be able to see www subdomain pointed to Heroku, can you try to remove the A record.

I would recommend using DNS service like DNSimple/Cloudflare or in case you don't want to go out of Heroku you can try pointDNS

Comment: this not allow to remove

Comment: just update my answer, but you can remove a record. if this is not allowing directly then try to update it and then delete it